# On the notion of core in Boolean-valued models

Tags: set-theory

John Bell introduces the notion of **core** as follows:

Suppose $u ∈ V^{(B)}$, then we call $v ⊆ V^{(B)}$ a core of $u$ if for all $x ∈ v$ we have $[\![ x \in u ]\!] = 1$ and for all $y \in V^{(B)}$ such that $[\![y \in u]\!] = 1$ there exists a unique $x ∈ v$ such that $[\![x = y ]\!]= 1$.

My question is the following. Let  $u = \langle\emptyset, a\rangle$ where $a\neq 1$. Is the core of $u$ simply the empty set?

Comment: Explain notations $u \in V^{(B)}, \ u=<\emptyset, a>$ (what is the meaning of $<,>$ ?), etc. which are absolutely non-standard.  Besides, who is John Bell ? Please, provide the name of the book he has probably written...

Comment: Hey! Yes of course. $V^B$ is the universe of B-valued sets, where each set is a function that takes values in a complete boolean algebra B. So u is simply a b-valued set. John Bells book is called Boolean valued models and indepedence proofs.

Comment: @JeanMarie: John Bell is a mathematician, of course. And he wrote the book "Set Theory: Boolean-Valued Models and Independence Proofs"

Comment: @JeanMarie Those notations are **not** non-standard - they're perfectly standard within the subfield of the question (fine, I'd use "$V^B$" instead of "$V^{(B)}$," but meh). Using them without definition is no worse than asking a question about schemes without defining schemes.

Comment: All right, "non-standard" wasn't the right qualificative. But, once again, when notations are a barrier to understanding, the OP should give at least a reference for people not familiar with the domian. For example, when I see $V$, I think to a set of vertices in a graph because it is in a domain that I am familiar with ; for letter $B$, I decripted almost immediately that it is $\{0,1\}$ and I understood that it was the set of all functions when from $B$ to $V$ but not very sure of it...

Comment: I think you mean $u=\{\langle \emptyset,a\rangle\}$. I think you’re right that the core is the empty set, since there is nothing that is an element of $u$ with probability one.

Comment: @JeanMarie "the OP should give at least a reference for people not familiar with the domian." Do we demand, for example, that all questions about schemes or modular forms or bornological spaces include such a reference? (If we do, that's fine, but in my experience we don't, and it seems odd to single out some topics.) That said, a good source is Jech's set theory book, $V$ is [the set-theoretic universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_hierarchy), $B$ is an arbitrary Boolean algebra, and $V^B$ is the associated $B$-valued model.

Comment: My rule of thumb for terminology etc. is the following: terms should be defined when (not necessarily only when) it is reasonably possible for the question to be answered, or for anything like it to be asked, by someone not already knowing those terms. So e.g. most questions about schemes don't need to define schemes since it's unreasonable to expect that someone not already knowing what a scheme is would either come up with a version of that question or have a chance of answering it. This falls into the same category.

Comment: (I stress this because I've frequently seen logic singled out in this sense, and it's frustrating to have one field held to a higher standard of accessibility despite having comparably technical topics. I'd have no problem if we *(MSE, not you personally - this is a general peeve of mine)* were consistent about it and required background sources for all technically heavy questions, but that's currently not something generally done. Moreover, I'm sensitive to such inconsistencies when the OP is a relatively new contributor - I wouldn't react nearly so strongly if this were one of my questions.)